# How to pass parameter on thank you page by CF7

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce, contact-form-7

I'm using contact form 7 (Cf7) for my Wordpress Site, I need to pass a variable in URL when form get submitted

i.e.

after submitting the for I need URL like this.

```
www.mysite.com/thank-you/?name="test"&email="test@test.com"&phone="0123456789"
```

Comment: Did you get any further here? Trying something similar : )

Answer (score -1):

For now, you can just enter this code in the additional settings tabs in Contact Form 7:

```
on_sent_ok: "location.replace('http://example.com');"
```

And then of course just enter the url you want in place of example.com. This should work, but Contact Form 7 is moving away from this, so here's an updated way to do it that should work better for the future: https://contactform7.com/redirecting-to-another-url-after-submissions/

Comment: thanks for the reply..but i want to pass the paramter in url using cf7